# Proving that the Čech complex is actually a complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

All authors I have seen handwave the proof of the Čech complex actually being a complex as a calculation. But I tried to do it and I don't see how it works. Maybe there's a mistake in my calculation.

For a sheaf $F$ and the cover $\{ U_i \}$, I want $C^p \xrightarrow{d} C^{p+1} \xrightarrow{d} C^{p+2}$, $d \circ d = 0$. To calculate,
\begin{align}
(d(ds))_{i_0, \ldots, i_{p+2}} &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{p+2} (-1)^k (ds)_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2}} \rvert_{U_{i_0, \ldots, i_{p+2}}} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{p+2} (-1)^k \left.\left( \sum\limits_{\substack{l=0 \\ l\neq k}}^{p+2} (-1)^l s_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_l}, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2}} \rvert_{U_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2}}} \right) \right\rvert_{U_{i_0, \ldots, i_{p+2}}} \\
&= \sum\limits_{\substack{k, l = 0 \\ k \neq l}}^{p+2} (-1)^{k+l} s_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_l}, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2}} \rvert_{U_{i_0, \ldots, i_{p+2}}}
\end{align}

The last equality uses that $U_{i_0, \ldots, i_{p+2}} \subseteq U_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2}}$. How can I see from here that this sum reduces to $0$?

Comment: Divide the sum into parts $k<l$ and $l<k$. Note which terms are formally the same but differ by sign.

Comment: This is what I don't understand. For some indeces $\alpha < \beta$, the corresponding term in the sum $k<l$ is for $k = \alpha, l = \beta$, and the one in the sum $l < k$ is $l = \alpha, k= \beta$. But both of these terms have sign $(-1)^{\alpha + \beta}$. I'm sorry I'm making a silly mistake.

Comment: When you delete $k$ you have to 'jump' over it when you sum $k>l$. This means that you introduce an extra $-1$ sign. i.e. something looking like this $\sum^{p+1}_{k=0}\left(\sum^{k-1}_{l=0}(-1)^{k+l}s_{i_0,\dots,\hat i_l,\dots,\hat i_k,\dots,i_{p+2}}+\sum^{p+2}_{l=k+1}(-1)^{k+(l-1)} s_{i_0,\dots,\hat i_k,\dots,\hat i_l,\dots,i_{p+2}}\right)$.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I made a mistake when I made explicit $(ds)_{i_0, \ldots, \hat{i_k}, \ldots, i_{p+2} }$, it should have sign $(-1)^{l-1}$ for $l>k$. Thank you, now it makes sense.